# Printing form with click of Button in WinForm C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

On my WinForm application I have a button (printBtn) and I want to print whatever on the form (radios, images, current state) to be printed with the click event.

Would it be possible to get the same dialogue wizard which guides through the process during print such as preview, send to pdf etc.

I am using VS2010 (the express guy) and C# 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this thread out: [How to print windows form in C# application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/eb80fbbe-6b89-4c3d-9ede-88a2b105c714)